# Call a function with 'arguments' as separate arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm trying to pass the `arguments` variable of a function as *separate* arguments to another function. I tried this:

```
function call_function(func) {
    func(arguments);
}
```

However, `call_function(someFunction, 123, 456)` actually calls `someFunction([someFunction, 123, 456])`. Regardless of the function itself being passed, it is passed as an `Arguments` object/array-like thing, but I'd rather call the function in this case as `someFunction(123, 456)`.

What I also tried is: `func(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))` to remove the function (first argument), but obviously this actually returns an array, i.e. it passes the array as the first argument to the function.

How could I code `call_function` so that a call like `call_function(someFunction, 123, 456)` results in `someFunction(123, 456)` being called?

Comment: What is the original problem you are trying to solve? Why would you need to call a function this way?

Comment: @Andrey: It was more theoretical actually.

Comment: I think TJHeuvel's answer is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @Andrey: You're completely right, I was just off for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function to call a function with the array as arguments.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply